# call image picker controller delegate method from another method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using Image picker Controller to take pictures and save them into database. I have this method to to get the image taken by the camera.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

This method is getting called automatically as it is delegated as self. I tried to call this ,when I click a button,but I couldn't get the image . It is showing me null.Here is the method I am calling the picker controller delegate method.

```
- (IBAction)save_Image:(id)sender {

UIImagePickerController *saveDelegate;
NSDictionary *infoDelegate;

[self imagePickerController:(saveDelegate) didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(infoDelegate)];

UIImage *chosenImage = infoDelegate[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

 //here i couldn't get the image. I am getting null
}
```

Is there any possible way that I can get the image by calling that method from my own method?

Comment: `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` will only return an image if you enabled the `allowsEditing` property. Use `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` instead.

Comment: Hi, I am not looking for edited image or original image. I am trying to get that image by calling that method from another method. @GuyKogus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inform others of when a user picks an image, this is a perfect place to use notifications.

```
static NSString* const ImagePickerDidFinishPickingPhotoNotification = @"ImagePickerDidFinishPickingPhotoNotification";

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ImagePickerDidFinishPickingPhotoNotification
                                                        object:picker
                                                      userInfo:info];
}

@end
```